# Invalid bitfield flag or number: 37035584

Tags: javascript, ejs

I am working on a bot dashboard and currently the dashboard page doesn't want to display. Now I don't know my issue at all.

**dashboard.ejs**

```js
<div class="servers">
<% user.guilds.forEach(guild => {
 const permsOnGuild = new perms(guild.permissions);
 if(!permsOnGuild.has("MANAGE_GUILD")) {
 return
 }
%>
```

**Error**

```js
RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: /home/runner/switch-beta-bot/dashboard/templates/dashboard.ejs:22
    20| 
    21| <div class="servers">
 >> 22| <% user.guilds.forEach(guild => {
    23|  const permsOnGuild = new perms(guild.permissions);
    24|  if(!permsOnGuild.has("MANAGE_GUILD")) {
    25|  return

Invalid bitfield flag or number: 37035584.
    at Function.resolve (/home/runner/switch-beta-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:152:11)
    at new BitField (/home/runner/switch-beta-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:17:38)
    at new Permissions (/home/runner/switch-beta-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/Permissions.js:11:1)
    at eval ("/home/runner/switch-beta-bot/dashboard/templates/dashboard.ejs":23:23)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at eval ("/home/runner/switch-beta-bot/dashboard/templates/dashboard.ejs":22:20)
    at dashboard (/home/runner/switch-beta-bot/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:692:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/home/runner/switch-beta-bot/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:272:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/runner/switch-beta-bot/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (/home/runner/switch-beta-bot/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/home/runner/switch-beta-bot/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/home/runner/switch-beta-bot/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/runner/switch-beta-bot/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
    at renderTemplate (/home/runner/switch-beta-bot/dashboard/dashboard.js:132:11)
    at /home/runner/switch-beta-bot/dashboard/dashboard.js:633:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/runner/switch-beta-bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: What does your `permissions` array look like?

Comment: currently what is in my dashboard.js file is ```lang-js 
renderTemplate(res, req, "dashboard.ejs", {
        perms: Discord.Permissions,
        userExists: user,
      });```
I still do not know where the error is originating from.

Comment: Please add any extra information to your post. Not into a comment.

Comment: I mean for the "gulld" roles. [See this other bug about the same error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63522829/rangeerror-bitfield-invalid-invalid-bitfield-flag-or-number) I don't know if it applies because you didn't post very much code.

Comment: What I am trying to to is show every server the user would have the Manage Guild permission onto the website, and currently that is showing the BitField Error my bot is running on discord.js V13 so I don't know where the error is coming from.

Comment: what is `guild.permissions` actually?

Comment: Well I just changed `guild.permissions` to `perms.FLAGS.MANAGE_GUILD` and `"MANAGE_GUILD"` to the same thing and the error no longer generates, but now it is showing every guild the user is in. How would I go by making it to only the guilds that the user is able to manage the guild will show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about a few hours I actually found the fix to the code. It wasn't as easy as it looks.

**NEW CODE**

```js
<% user.guilds.forEach(guild => {
 if(guild.permissions !== 2147483647) {
 return;
 }
%>
```

Now that solves my issue.