# RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: undefined discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was coding my discord bot but when I turned on it today, I received this error

```
RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: undefined.
```

I've already tried to write "npm uninstall discord.js" and then "npm install discord.js@13.9.0" in the terminal but this error still appear.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: There is an existing entry that may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63522829/rangeerror-bitfield-invalid-invalid-bitfield-flag-or-number

Comment: You should edit your question and add the full error message and some relevant code here

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Idk where is the real problem with the code, that's why I'm asking for help here

Comment: @AndreasFritsch yeah I've already seen it but I'm still stuck in the same problem

Comment: @Viciox That's what stack traces are for and that's the reason I was asking for the full error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RangeError \[BITFIELD\_INVALID\]: Invalid bitfield flag or number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63522829/rangeerror-bitfield-invalid-invalid-bitfield-flag-or-number)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14)